# MSBuild or NAnt script that generates C# files, adds them to a project and compiles the project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nant

I've just written a code generator app for FluentMigrator API that emits an unknown number of C# class files. I wish to compile the code generator, run it to emit the C# classes then add the new C# files to an existing C# project and then compile final solution.

What's the best approach for adding the code generated C# files to a project?

Comment: Create a UsingTask that consumes your code generator, and have the code generator emit into the $(IntermediateOutput) directory and have it output the file names into an ItemGroup, then merge that ItemGroup into the Compile item group.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm a newbie to MSBuild. I've created the Task class for the CodeGen and it works fine. Can you show some sample MSBuild XML for this.

Comment: - Not sure how make my MSBuild task emit files into an ItemGroup or how to merge them into the Compile item group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what we know from your post, there could be a couple approaches.

You have an API that will generate some class files and want to integrate this into your build process so you would make an API call to generate new class files, then incorporate those class files into your build.

If your executable emits output files into it's current working directory, you could use an Exec task to run your command in the $(IntermeidateOutputPath) so as to not clutter up your project's source tree:

```
<Exec Command="MyExe.exe " WorkingDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AutoGenClasses\" />
```

Following this command, you could append those output classes into the default compile group:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AutoGenClasses\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now you'd probably want to control when this occurs, so you'd embed this code into a separate `<Target />` and schedule it to occur before the build occurs.

```
<Target Name="AutoGenClasses" BeforeTargets="Compile">
  <Message Text="Starting the AutoGenClasses task..." Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="MyExe.exe " WorkingDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AutoGenClasses\" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AutoGenClasses\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="... completed the AutoGenClasses." Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. That helps. The BeforeTargets="Compile" trick is cool.  

My code gen app actually includes an MSBuild Task class as an alternative to running it from command line args.   This includes this property that I hoped to use to return the class files. I guess either way works.
        [Output]
        public ITaskItem[] OutputClassFiles { get; private set; }

Comment: You could still use that, just implement as an inline task with the UsingTask task, then import your OutputClassFiles into the @Compile ItemGroup.